# Why am I getting a MissingMethodException for get_ConsoleOut() in MSpec?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mspec

I've created many MSpec classes before but running unit tests in a file I created recently gave the below error. Has anyone encountered this with their unit tests?

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Machine.Specifications.Result.get_ConsoleOut()'.

Here is the code:

```
[Subject(typeof(UsersDao))]
public class query_for_a_specific_user
{
    private static Context context1;
    private static Filter queryFilter;
    private static List<User> users;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        context1 = new Context() { DatabaseId = 1 };
        queryFilter = new Filter() { UserId = 1223 };
    };

    Because of = () => { users = UsersDao.GetUsers(context1, queryFilter); };

    It should_not_be_null = () => users.ShouldNotBeNull();
    It should_not_be_empty = () => users.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
}
```

Comment: `Because of = () =>` is that valid code? I have never worked with `mspec` before, so it could be.

Comment: It is, you'd normally use Action.  MSpec is about "removing language noise".  Adding louder noise is a valid strategy.  Sure drowns-out any way to map this code to the exception message though, hard to get help with that.  One expert around, he stops by once a month or so.

Comment: It's hard to analyze based on this information. Can you give more details like the full stack trace and the code under test?

Comment: It's very strange because this format of testing worked fine in the past. I don't have a stack trace either. It's just the error shown in the Unit Test Sessions window when I run the test.

Comment: When I debug I get this warning but I've checked the DLL is still successfully referenced.

    Warning 8 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly 
    "Machine.Specifications.TDNetRunner". Check to make sure the assembly 
    exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code,
    you may get compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely a version mismatch between the MSpec runner and the MSpec.dll referenced by your project. 0.5.16 (don't remember exactly) added support for capturing console output, and the error stems from the fact that your MSpec.dll doesn't yet have that support. Can you please make sure all versions match up an rerun the tests?